# Storing Json data issues in Yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I have to save the data in this format {"dashboard_layout":[9,10,5]}.
But Currently my data is saving in this format.{"dashboard_layout":["9,5","10,5"]}.

For example If $id=5 then I have to store the data in  {"dashboard_layout":[9,10,5]}

```
 public function actionDashboardBlockAdd(){
    if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $model = \app\models\UserPreferences::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id])->one();
        // check here if model is not null 
        $perferencesOther = json_decode($model->others);

      if(!empty($perferencesOther) && isset($perferencesOther->dashboard_layout)) {
            $dashboardLayout = [];   
            foreach ($perferencesOther->dashboard_layout as $key => $value) {                  
                    $dashboardLayout[] = $value.','.$id;  
            } 

            $perferencesOther->dashboard_layout = $dashboardLayout;                
            // store updated preferencves in db
            $model->others = json_encode($perferencesOther); 
            $model->save();

        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => true,
            'value'=>$model->others
        ]); 
         }
    } else {
        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => false,              
        ]);
    } 
}
```

Can someone help me to solve the issue???

Comment: Because you're generating such data in `$dashboardLayout[] = $value.','.$id;`?

Comment: @rob can you tell me how can I resolve this one.I just want to append the $id into that array ....{"dashboard_layout":[9,10,5]} like this

Comment: Put `$dashboardLayout[] = $id` after `foreach`.

Comment: I tried that one that time It save only {"dashboard_layout":["10,5"]} like this.here first value 9 is missing and is in string format with"" quotes.I want this format {"dashboard_layout":[9,10,5]}

Comment: it's confusing , you are appending the `id` with every `value` in the `$perferencesOther->dashboard_layout` array if the `value` is not equal to the posted `id` ? and on the other hand you are saying that you want to append the id into the array? you should explain more clearly your given logic does not do what you are saying here in the comments.

Comment: also under what condition you want the `$id` to be added to the array, if that `$id` does not exist in the whole array or ...you want to match every value inside the array and if it is not equal to the `$id` you want to append the id to that specific `value` with comma `,`?

Comment: I removed that condition.I just want to append the $id into the {"dashboard_layout":[9,10]}.for example  if $id=5 then {"dashboard_layout":[9,10,5]}.

Comment: i got the answer.updated my answer

Comment: so you have got the answer? or you want to say you updated the question

Comment: yeah I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function actionDashboardBlockAdd(){
    if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $model = \app\models\UserPreferences::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id])->one();
        // check here if model is not null 
        $perferencesOther = json_decode($model->others);

      if(!empty($perferencesOther) && isset($perferencesOther->dashboard_layout)) {
            $dashboardLayout = [];   
            foreach ($perferencesOther->dashboard_layout as $key => $value) {                  
                    $dashboardLayout[] = $value;  
            } 
            array_push($dashboardLayout,$id);
            $perferencesOther->dashboard_layout = $dashboardLayout;                
            // store updated preferencves in db
            $model->others = json_encode($perferencesOther,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
            $model->save();

        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => true,
            'value'=>$model->others
        ]); 
         }
    } else {
        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => false,              
        ]);
    } 
}
```

using array_push solved my issues

Comment: Do you know that `array_push($dashboardLayout,$id)` works the same as `$dashboardLayout[] = $id` (I proposed this yesterday in comment), only slower?